# Excel - long pause after changing first input post manual recalculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with a reasonable sized .xlsx file (10mb) and have my calculations set to manual.  Each time I update an input in my file for the *first* time after I manually recalc, there is an approximately 20 second delay after hitting enter/moving to a new cell.

Thereafter, I can make any number of input changes without any delay, but after I then recalc my file the same problem occurs on the next (and now first) input change.

I've tried to troubleshoot the problem, removing all my OFFSET formulae in both cells and data validation, then deleting conditional formatting, but nothing seems to resolve this issue.

Has anyone come across this issue before and knows a solution as its something I'm not familiar with.

Thanks,
M

Comment: 10mb for an Excel file is pretty much. ¿Any connection to an external datasource? ¿Maybe too many graphs? I don't know what kind of data are you working with but Excel **is not** a database software. Consider trying to use database solutions (SQL, Access, and so on).

Comment: Thanks. For added context, it is a financial model and I regularly work with files 20MB + which do not have this problem.  Indeed, the calculation time is <1sec which is the odd part.  I deleted a core calculation worksheet since posting to test and that solves the problem, but isn't an acceptable solution. There is nothing out of the ordinary on that sheet, and I tried deleting all conditional formatting + volatile formulae on that worksheet to no avail.